Logical form, Wittgenstein
The question is going to be about TLP, not Philosophical investigations.
I know that a logical form of a proposition can't be represented in the proposition itself.
But can it be represented by the means of another proposition?

The logical form of a proposition is shown by the proposition but cannot be said (represented) in any proposition, i.e. cannot be "pictured" by it, see SEP. "Things that cannot be put into words. They make themselves manifest" TLP 6.522.

Tractatus is sometimes very puzzling...
The "logical analysis" of a statemetn like "Socrates is Greek" as g(S) as well as "a is to the Right of b" as aRb (predicate logic-like) is present into the Tractatus: see e.g. 4.1211 and 3.1432; see also 3.325:

"In order to avoid such errors we must make use of a sign-language [the Begriffschrifft] that excludes them by not using the
same sign for different symbols and by not using in a superficially similar way signs that have different modes of signification: that is to say, a sign-language that is governed by logical grammar—by logical syntax.(The conceptual notation of Frege and Russell is such
a language, though, it is true, it fails to exclude all mistakes.)"

And see 4.0031 "All philosophy is a ‘critique of language’. It was Russell who performed the service of showing that the apparent logical form of a proposition need not be its real one [see On Denoting]."
But then we have 4.121:

Propositions cannot represent logical form: it is mirrored in them.
What finds its reflection in language, language cannot represent.
What expresses itself in language, we cannot express by means of language. Propositions show the logical form of reality.

And 4.0312

The possibility of propositions is based on the principle
that objects have signs as their representatives. My fundamental idea is that the ‘logical constants’ are not representatives; that there can be no representatives of the logic of facts.

In conclusion, logical form is what is common to the every picture of reality in order to be able to represent it.
The fundamental distiction is that between representing (a fact "mirroring" another fact) and showing and the connected idea that "logical constants" are syncategorematic i.e. there is no "logical object" corresponding to the symbol ∼ for negation.

Some more hints:

6.23 When two expressions can be substituted for one
another, that characterizes their logical form.

This is reminiscent of Frege's concept of function: the key difference between function and object is that the symbol for a function cannot be replaced into the "slot" of the function itself (producing the problematic f(f) - see 3.333) because that slot is the placeholder for the symbol of an object (a name).
See also Some Remarks on Logical Form (1929):

Every proposition has a content and a form. We get
the picture of the pure form if we abstract from the meaning
of the single words, or symbols (so far as they have
independent meanings).


@MauroALLEGRANZA "It was Russell who performed the service of showing that the apparent logical form of a proposition need not be its real one [see On Denoting]."" If there is such a thing as the "apparent logical form of a proposition", then how come Russell could tell that some other form is the real one? And if this other one is also apparent, then presumably it also needs not be the real one either. You are only repeating unsupported claims.

@Speakpigeon - as you can see "It was..." is a quotation. The statement is in W's text.


I know that a logical form of a proposition can't be represented in the proposition itself. But can it be represented by the means of another proposition?

Rather than the notion of proposition, which is either redundant or incomprehensible, let us talk of meaningful sentences. At least we all understand what that is. The sort of proposition Wittgenstein is talking about could not possibly be exhibited in any shape or form. People who use "proposition" in this sense, for example Bertrand Russell, all have to use sentence to "express propositions", as they would put it. Well, let's cut the middle man, forget propositions and talk of sentences instead.
The only logical form of a meaningful sentence that we can actually exhibit and possibly talk sensibly about is just another meaningful sentence. For example, the logical form of the sentence "The king of France is bald" is the sentence:

Kx → Bx

This sentence is meaningful if only we take x to denote something, K to stand for the predicate "the king of France" and B for the predicate "bald", so that Kx just means "something is the king of France" and Bx "it is bald.
We also need to take the symbol → to stand for the implication, so that A → B just means "A implies B", which is true if and only if it is true that if A is true, then B is true.
That there is no other species of logical form follows from what the word "form" means. That could be different if we talked of the logical structure, although again not necessarily.
Thus, by logical form, we just means another sentence, but a sentence of a so-called "formal language", as if a language could be "not formal". The main characteristic of a so-called "formal language" is that it involves unambiguously defined symbols rather than natural language words. Very convenient, but that doesn't make expression somehow not that of a language.
The situation is simple. We can only communicate with each other about complex ideas by using an articulated language. There is no proposition which we can reasonably talk about which is not, in fact, a sentence. So, the logical form of a sentence can only be another sentence in some purpose-built language.
Given this, it is simply absurd to say that the "logical form of a proposition can't be represented in the proposition itself". In my example, the logical form of the proposition (sentence) "Kx → Bx" is just "Kx → Bx", i.e., itself.
The logical form of the sentence "The king of France is bald" is also expressed by the sentence itself. This follows from the fact it is necessarily its own logical form, only in a natural language, rather than in some purpose-built language. If that wasn't true, I wonder how anyone could possibly guess it's logical form. By reading the entrails of slaughtered a chicken?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
